# use NodeJs Buffer class from client side

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer

I am using nodejs Buffer class (http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html) to parse some raw data and make use a lot of all its methods.
However I'd like to use it on the client side as I don't need a server for what I am doing (mostly parsing the data).

Is there a simple way to access all the methods from the Buffer class on the client side?

Many thanks

Comment: Although this may not be completely stable, it's a good reference. https://github.com/arextar/browser-buffer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[browserify](http://browserify.org/) contains a Buffer implementation for the browser, among other node core modules.

Comment: These days this lives here: https://github.com/feross/buffer