# How to use node Buffer module in a client side browser - detailed explanation required please

Tags: javascript, node.js, client

First things first. I know that there are other questions that are similar to this e.g. [use NodeJs Buffer class from client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25847799/use-nodejs-buffer-class-from-client-side) or
[How can I use node.js buffer library in client side javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56237161/how-can-i-use-node-js-buffer-library-in-client-side-javascript)

However, I don't understand how to make use of the reference to use browserify though it is given approval.

Here is my Node code:

```
import { Buffer } from 'buffer/';
```

I know this is the ES6 equivalent of require.

I would like a javaScript file implementation of this module so that I can simply use the standard html file reference:

```
<script src=./js/buffer.js></script>
```

And then use it as in for example

```
return new Buffer(temp).toString('utf-8');
```

This simply falls over with the

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined
```

no matter how I create the buffer.js file.

So using the browserify idea I've tried using the standalone script (from the https://www.npmjs.com/package/buffer as https://bundle.run/buffer@6.0.3 )

I've created a test.js file and put

```
var Buffer = require('buffer/').Buffer
```

in it and then run browserify on it as

```
browserify test.js -o buffer.js
```

and many other variations.
I'm not getting anywhere. I know I must be doing something silly that reflects my ignorance. Maybe you can help educate me please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These instructions worked for me.  Cheers!

Here are the instructions you can look at the web section.
https://github.com/feross/buffer

Here is what the instructions state about using it in the browser without browserify.  So from what you tried

```
 browserify test.js -o buffer.js
```

I would just use the version directly that does not require browserify

To use this module directly (without browserify), install it:

npm install buffer

To depend on this module explicitly (without browserify), require it like this:

var Buffer = require('buffer/').Buffer  // note: the trailing slash is important!

Comment: Thanks, though it's been a while and I've forgotten what I was trying to achieve now ... lol

Comment: By serendipity I'm now going to need buffer for dealing with bluetooth stuff on React-Native so this will be very useful. :)